# How to run Android Studio Emulator in Windows 10?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, android-studio-3.6

I am new to Android Studio and the purpose I use Android Studio is just for the emulator, not to develop apps etc. I am using the latest Android Studio version 3.6. I want to do mobile performance testing on LoadRunner, and I will use Android Studio Emulator instead of real device. The problem now is, I only can run the emulator in the Android Studio apps itself. The performance test tools will need the emulator exe path. May I know if I can run the emulator in a standalone apps? Such as run in Windows in exe file? So far I know, when I downloaded the Android SDK package, it doesn't include the emulator.exe file.

I tried searching and tried the suggested solutions already but not working. May I know what's the problem here?

[Using emulation to record mobile applications](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/2020/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/c_Recording_with_Emulation_Web_HTTP.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use Android Studio

I would suggest something like genymotion for personal use.

https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/

Comment: But so far I know, Genymotion isn't free for use, that's why I prefer Android Studio more compared to Genymotion. Do you ever used Android Studio emulator?

Comment: if it's for personal use it's  totally free